# BERT fine-tuning for Conversational AI

Tags: nlp, chatbot, bert-language-model

I am trying to build a conversational AI chatbot. Since BERT is quite a popular model, I am thinking about using it. I can see that BERT has a pre-trained model for the Question Answering task. Can anyone tell me which version of the BERT model should I use to build a conversation AI? Or Can anyone direct me to the useful resources?

Thanks in advance!